# Responsive webpage accordion in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I almost finish the webpage and I know how to collapse the content, but I still have no idea how to show the content directly, but show them in accordion style in mobile devices without duplicating it.

Here is my code and I use Bootstrap to make accordion.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title ">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" >Collapsible Group 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to make much sense out of what you are asking or what specific issue is. What does *"how to show the content directly"* or *"without duplicating it"* mean?

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate content? Use css  breakpoints to make design changes for different screen resolutions.

Comment: I need to make the content shows directly in large screen and  collapse them in accordion style when viewed in small devices. and the content should not be duplicated.

Comment: Why do you have the class ```hidden-xs``` on the first panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't duplicate the content and use the bootstrap hidden helper classes, then you could do this with javascript.

First, remove your data attributes that initialize the accordion on all screen sizes.

Second, initialize the accordion based on screen size.

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
  $('#accordion').find('.panel-collapse').addClass('collapse')
  $('#accordion').find('.panel-title a').attr('data-toggle','collapse')
  $('#accordion').collapse()
}
```

Comment: I have a question about it.... what do you mean about "remove your data attributes that initialize the accordion on all screen sizes."

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it works for you.